# How can I insert block content between post templates within the query loop block?

Tags: full-site-editing

On a custom post type archive page how do you hook into the query loop block to, for example, add a CTA between the 3rd and 4th item in the list?

Article #1
Article #2
Article #3
Subscribe to our newsletter
Article #4
...

Comment: I wonder if this is not possible with the query loop block and the post template. However, it does look like I can use php templates. One thing that took me a minute to figure out is that the blog index template needs to be named home.php. archive-{post_type}.php works as expected. I found lots of useful details about php templates in FSE themes here: https://fullsiteediting.com/lessons/how-to-use-php-templates-in-block-themes/